# How can i use SQL inner join statement as query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
SELECT
    Id,
    No,
    NetAmount,
    PaidAmount,
    NetAmount - PaidAmount AS AmountToBePayed
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.Id,
            m.No,
            SUM(NetAmount) as NetAmount,
            (
                SELECT
                    COALESCE( SUM( PaidAmount ), 0 )
                FROM
                    A_Account_Payable_Payment_Invoice
            ) as PaidAmount
        FROM
            A_Account_Payable_Invoice_M m
            INNER JOIN A_Account_Payable_Invoice_Item d ON
                m.Id = d.A_Account_Payable_Invoice
        GROUP BY
            m.Id,
            m.No
    ) a
```

How can i use this query directly in LINQ C#

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes i tried to use this query directly in LINQ but i can'not
I just want to use this query and get result in LIST

Comment: Ok then please add your LINQ codes to Question.

Comment: var que=db.Database.SqlQuery("SQL Query")

Comment: So as far as I understand you don't want to translate this SQL ve LINQ, you just want to call this script from EF or something, am I right?

Comment: @AyeshaSheikh You can use the tools below in my answer for the required conversion of your `SQL` query. If you directly want to call a query (which will be complicated) in your case, you can refer to this: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql

Comment: Thankyou so much it worked

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned on comment section you don't want to translate SQL to LINQ, you just want to directly run this script.

To do so first you need to create class that will match with your Script like:

```
 [DataContract()]
 public class PaymentInvoiceResult
 {
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int No { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int NetAmount { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PaidAmount { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int AmountToBePayed { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you need to use [`SqlQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql) as following:

```
List<PaymentInvoiceResult> paymentInvoiceResultList = db.Database.SqlQuery<PaymentInvoiceResult>("Your Script").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
var results = db.ExecuteQuery(typeof(DTO), "sql query ");
```

Your dto should have members:

```
Id,
    No,
    NetAmount,
    PaidAmount,
    NetAmount - PaidAmount AS AmountToBePayed
```

Comment: You can mark it as answer as it will help other members:). Cheers